# R - find columns where all values are either NA or single value (0 variance)

Tags: r

I'm dealing with a data frame containing several columns that are a single value or NA's.  I know how to find columns that are one or the other:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = 1:10, col2 = 0, col3 = seq(1,20,2))
df1[c(1,4,7),'col2'] <- NA


names(df1)[sapply(df1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) == length(x))]
names(df1)[sapply(df1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == length(x))]
```

However I can't think of a way to catch all NA's or a single value.  In the above case `col2` should be caught.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

First you could check for the existence of NA within a column with:

```
any(is.na(df1$col2))
```

Then if you want to know if a column has all values set to zero without taking into consideration the NA values, use simply:

```
all(df1$col2 == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Using **rowSums** as alex2006 suggests might lead to the inconvenience that you have an arrange of numbers whose sum is 0 and it would also flag that column.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for columns were the variance is 0 you could try

```
colvar0<-apply(df1,2,function(x) var(x,na.rm=T)==0)

colvar0

 col1  col2  col3 
FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

to get the column names

```
names(df1)[colvar0]
```

edit: suppose you have some columns with only NA then colvar0 equals NA, you can retrieve all the column names with

```
names(df1)[colvar0|is.na(colvar0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following will do it.

```
sapply(df1, function(x){
    na <- is.na(x)
    any(na) && length(unique(x[!na])) == 1
})
# col1  col2  col3 
#FALSE  TRUE FALSE


inx <- sapply(df1, function(x){
    na <- is.na(x)
    any(na) && length(unique(x[!na])) == 1
})

df1[which(inx)]
#   col2
#1    NA
#2     0
#3     0
#4    NA
#5     0
#6     0
#7    NA
#8     0
#9     0
#10    0

df1[which(!inx)]
#   col1 col3
#1     1    1
#2     2    3
#3     3    5
#4     4    7
#5     5    9
#6     6   11
#7     7   13
#8     8   15
#9     9   17
#10   10   19
```

Note: If you just want the column names, `names[inx]` gets the ones with variance zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
sapply(df1, function(x) length(unique(sort(x))) %in% 0:1)  #sort removes NA
# col1  col2  col3 
#FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

OR

```
sapply(df1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) %in% 0:1)
# col1  col2  col3 
#FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the actual row where this is happening I suggest the following:

```
which(is.na(rowSums(df1)) | rowSums(df1)==0)
```

Comment: Not to be rude, but this answer seems very much unrelated to the question of the OP. This gives any row that contains any value of NA or a 0, the OP specifically asks for columns that contain only NA and/or constant

Comment: @Niek: I changed the question after this answer was posted.  The fault is mine.